# Is there a proxy webserver that routes dynamically requests based on URLs?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I am looking for a way how to dynamically route requests through proxy webserver. I will explain what I need exactly and what I have found so far.

I would like to have some lightweight webserver (thinking about node.js or nginx) set up as proxy webserver with public IP. It would route requests to different local webservers based on URLs. But not only based on hostname but based on full URL.

My idea is, that this proxying webserver would use either local memory cache, memcached or redis to look up key-value based information of URL and local webserver.

I have found these projects:

- https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
- https://www.steve.org.uk/Software/node-reverse-proxy/
- https://github.com/hipache/hipache

They all seem to do similar things, but not exactly what I am looking for, that is:

- URL based proxying (absolute URLs routing to different local webservers)
- use of memory based configuration storage / cache
- dynamically change configuration using API without reloading proxy webserver

Is there any better-suited project or is there a way how to configure one of three projects above to fit my requirements ?

Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does exactly what you want: https://openresty.org/en/dynamic-routing-based-on-redis.html

It's basically nginx with precompiled modules. You can setup the same by yourself with nginx + lua module + redis ( + of course the necessary lua rocks). OpenResty just makes it easier.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, would similar approach be possible with different language instead of Lua ?

Comment: Nginx can also have PERL modules if you prefer that. You just need to compile with perl support.